# How can we provide the access of single EC2 Instance to the IAM User Using AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

We have created an IAM User which is associated with the Custom Policy. Also added the same policy in the group of this particular user.
In the Policy we are providing this JSON for the IAM User:

```
   {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1392113879000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
         "ec2:StopInstances",
        "ec2:StartInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:instance/instance_id"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help us for the same.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So what is the problem? Any error messages?

Comment: What sort of access do you want? Do you mean the ability to SSH or RDP into the instance? That policy just lets the user start/stop an existing instance.